# Django breadcrumb using generic tools

Tags: python, django, breadcrumbs

I would like to use Django build-in tools to print breadcrumb string in the html-template file, for example like this:

```
domain_name/accounts/14
```

Where each part between `/` will lead to its corresponding page. Is it achievable using `{{ request.path }}` and https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/templates/builtins/ ?

The tasks I see:

1. Remove first slash '/' from the `{{ request.path }}'
2. Break `{{ request.path}}` value into pieces (divided by '/')
3. Apply link to each piece

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the string manipulation you want to do is possible from the template side. I think a possible way is using a custom template filter that receives request.path and returns a list of tuples (link, text) and then iterate over that list on the template side and create the breadcrumbs.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/custom-template-tags/#writing-custom-template-filters